# Bootstrap4 move login form towards to the center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have the following login page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title> Log in </title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
                  <header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-primary">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
<img src="https://loremimage.com/default/32/32/1" />
      Διαχείρηση Μελών ΕΛΛΑΚ Κύπρου
    </a>
          </nav>
</header>
            <div class="container-fluid d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
    <div class="row bg-light border border-primary">
      <div class="col mt-5 col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <h1 style="text-align:center">Log in</h1>
        <form action="/login_check" method="post">
              
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="username" name="_username" value="" placeholder="Username" required="required" />
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></span>
             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                 <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="_password" placeholder="Password" required="required" />
                 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
             </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="form-check">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="_remember_me" class="form-check-input" />
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="remember_me" >Remember me</label>
                  </div>
              </div>
             <div class="form-row">
               <div class="col">
                 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="_submit" name="_submit" value="Log in" />
               </div>
               <div class="col">
                 <a class="btn btn-warning btn-block" href="/resetting/request">I forgot my password</a>
               </div>
            </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 mt-1 mb-5">
          <a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="/register/">I do not have an account</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And my problem is that the login form is not too center as I want to as this [image](https://screenshots.firefox.com/46uR9NlqqQs2HJZn/192.168.10.10) shows.

What I want to do is to display like that:

[image: Display image]

So do you know how to move the whole login form towards the center I tried the bootstrap's `d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center` class combination and somehow it does center but the flexbox is as height as my login form.

So my guess is on how I can make the flexbox take over the whole remaining height. DO you know how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give height to your *container-fluid* `div` in view-port

```
height: calc(100vh - 60px);
```

*60px is your header height* (View in full-screen mode of snippet)

```css
.custom {
  height: calc(100vh - 60px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title> Log in </title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
                  <header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-primary">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
<img src="https://loremimage.com/default/32/32/1" />
      Διαχείρηση Μελών ΕΛΛΑΚ Κύπρου
    </a>
          </nav>
</header>
            <div class="custom container-fluid d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
    <div class="row bg-light border border-primary">
      <div class="col mt-5 col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <h1 style="text-align:center">Log in</h1>
        <form action="/login_check" method="post">
              
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="username" name="_username" value="" placeholder="Username" required="required" />
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></span>
             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                 <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="_password" placeholder="Password" required="required" />
                 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
             </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="form-check">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="_remember_me" class="form-check-input" />
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="remember_me" >Remember me</label>
                  </div>
              </div>
             <div class="form-row">
               <div class="col">
                 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="_submit" name="_submit" value="Log in" />
               </div>
               <div class="col">
                 <a class="btn btn-warning btn-block" href="/resetting/request">I forgot my password</a>
               </div>
            </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 mt-1 mb-5">
          <a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="/register/">I do not have an account</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```